# How do you scrape a specific variable/text on puppeteer with nodejs? also is there anyway to filter certain items within the array to exclude them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

So I wanted to get a little project started and the project is an order checker for Nike. It uses puppeteer to automate the entire thing. How it works is it'll open the guest order status page and the user will be prompted to input order number and email. After inputting, it will then scrape the info necessary and send a result back via Discord Webhooks. I'm kind of new to puppeteer so I'm completely lost with using which function for what I'm trying do. Basically within the discord web hook, there's a "size" field that would be pulled from the site and returned into the embed. The problem is, the

tag on the nike site isn't differentiated so its's either I scraped all the

tags within the div class or when I try to scrape a specific field, it returns undefined. Below is the block I'm trying to scrape.[image]

```
  const element = await page.$(".text-color-secondary");
    let size = await (await element.getProperty('Product Size')).jsonValue();
```

I tried using page.evaluate previously and this is what I currently just tried. I tried using page.$ to scrape a specific div class and return the property "Product Size" within the

tag but it returns undefined.

**UPDATE**
So originally I was either only able to scrape the "headline-5" class, which is not the end result I wanted. I went about it a new way where it'll scrape all of the items in data-testid and push it into an array and then returned/ Even though it's close to what I'm aiming for, it's still not 100%. Now it scrapes every

and pushes it into the embed. So I'm wondering, is there anyway to filter certain items within the array to exclude them?

````
    let sizeInfo = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let sizeTag = document.querySelectorAll(".responsive-body-3-2.mr12-lg.mb2-sm.pt3-sm.flx-gro-sm-1.flex-parent.d-sm-flx.flx-dir-sm-c.flx-jc-sm-sb.flx-ai-sm-fs");
        let size = [];
        sizeTag.forEach((tag) => {
            size.push(tag.innerText)
        })
        return size;
    });```
````

Comment: Please share the page URL and full code as a [mcve].

Comment: The URL is the order link to an actual order of mine I'm using to test and it has all of my personal info so I can't do that, as for full code I attached it here https://pastebin.com/4A8hKSir

Comment: Thanks, but code should be added as an [edit] as [text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) to the question itself.

Comment: apologize about that, but basically I'm trying to figure out how to get puppeteer to click an embedded href link

Comment: I understand that, but I can't really help without more information. The trouble is, every site has potentially complex, dynamic behavior, so just looking at your image and saying "run `page.click('[data-testid="Product Size"]')` (to click it) or `page.$eval('[data-testid="Product Size"]', el => el.textContent)` (to get the text)" won't be enough to solve the problem. But I have no additional info to go off of. This could be unselectable due to visibility, iframe, shadow dom or many other issues, like your script being blocked as a robot. It's anyone's guess.

Comment: gotcha I can definitely see that. Sorry for the late response. I've figured out a way to scrape the info, but it grabs all of the info from the first <p> to the last. Now I'm wondering if you can filter certain items that I'm scraping. Here's the code I have for it so you can get an idea. I'll update the post.